# Call Swift completion handler in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, completionhandler

I am trying to call a swift method, which is implemented like this:-

```
@objc class DataAPI: NSObject {
    func makeGet(place:NSString , completionHandler: (String! , Bool!) -> Void)
    {
        var str:String = ""
        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

        manager.GET("https://api.com", parameters: nil, success:
              { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
                        str = "JSON:  \(responseObject!.description)"
                        print(str)

                        completionHandler(str,false)   //str as response json, false as error value

            },
                    failure: { (operation,error: NSError!) in
                        str = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                        completionHandler("Error",true)   
        })

    }}
```

Now when I am trying to call it in my Objective C class, it is throwing an error **"No Visible interface for DataAPI declares selector makeGet:completionHandler"**

This is how I am calling the method in my Objective C class:-

```
[[DataAPI  new] makeGet:@"" completionHandler:^{
}];
```

Comment: can you help its not working in swift 5 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use !(ImplicitUnwrappedOptional) keyword in closure. That is not allow bridging to ObjC code. just remove ! from closure.

```
func makeGet(place:NSString , completionHandler: (String! , Bool!) -> Void)
```

to

```
func makeGet(place:NSString , completionHandler: (String , Bool) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 4):

I see that in `Swift` the completion handler has two arguments: `String` and `Bool` whereas in your `Objective-C` call you pass a block without any arguments. I think it may be the cause of the error.

Try:

```
[[DataAPI  new] makeGet:@"" completionHandler:^(NSString* string, BOOl b){
}];
```

Comment: That code is not working Andrey, but thanks for pointing out the issue. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean and Rebuild to generate the "YourModule-Swift.h" again with all your changes.
Then it should be something like this:

```
[[DataAPI  new] makeGet:@"" withCompletionHandler:^(NSString* string, BOOl b){
// your code here    
}];
```

If you still getting that error, your "YourModule-Swift.h" file hasn't been generated correctly. Check it!